# How to setup a RAM disk without using third-party software?

Tags: windows-7, ramdisk

How may I setup a RAM disk on my Windows 7 computer without using third-party software?  There seems to be a lot of third-party applications that can do this, but I am wondering if this is something that Windows already provides, perhaps through the command line interface or Administrator controls, that is not as intuitive as a nice GUI.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no ramdisk included with windows, you must use a 3rd party one.

They do have the source for a ramdisk in their [Driver Development Kit](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/windows-driver-kit-wdk-80-e3161626) that you could compile and install. But I would recommend going with a 3rd party solution as it will be much more robust than a quick SDK example (often example code will not be written with best practices because understandability is more important that perfect design when writing a example (whats the point of writing a example if your student is totally lost looking at it)).

Comment: The link in this answer is broken. It should either be corrected or removed.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [RAMDISK](https://web.archive.org/web/20120711233113/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544551(v=vs.85).aspx), part of the Windows Driver Kit. I've never used it, but it looks a lot like the old MS-DOS .sys file that you could use to make Ramdisks. Let us know if it works!

Comment: That is example code that must be complied, if you are going to download something I would recommend using something that has a community that you can ask for help (like a support forum) when something does not work right.

Comment: The link in this answer is broken. It should either be corrected or removed.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/guidoreina/ramdisk: "This is a modified version of the RAM disk sample driver from Microsoft, so that it is functional."